# Map icon is only showing the first character of my info window

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps

I am passing a string of lat/lons to my javascript crom the aspx underlying code. The map is displaying correctly but when you click the pin, it is only showing the first character of the pin.

Here is my c# code:

```
public string sdata;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  sdata = "Fred,26.2486591339111,-80.2002334594727|Tom,26.2344417572021,-80.1393356323242|Paul,26.0818271636963,-80.2083358764648|John,26.2701854705811,-80.1152496337891|Eric,26.2009468078613,-80.1440734863281";
}
```

Any my javascript:

```
  var data2 = '<%=sdata%>'.toString();
  var locations = data2.split('|');

  var loc = locations[0].split(",");
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(loc[1],loc[2]),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var marker, i;

  var pinColor = "#";
  for (k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
      pinColor += ("0" + (Math.random() * 256 | 0).toString(16)).substr(-2);
  }

  var pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|" + "#0000ff",
              new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
              new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
              new google.maps.Point(10, 34));
  var pinShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_shadow",
              new google.maps.Size(40, 37),
              new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
              new google.maps.Point(12, 35));

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      var loc = locations[i].split(",");
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(loc[1], loc[2]),
          //icon: pinImage,
          //shadow: pinShadow,
          map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
          return function () {
              infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
          }
      })(marker, i));
  }
```

My split seems to be working correctly:

[image]

This is what I see when I click on a pin:

[image]

I would assume that the issue is in the addListener(?) but I'm new to javascript and google maps.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: to address clarification

Your issue is that you are doing the comma split early in your handler's for loop but then referring to the unsplit version when pulling the first element - hence you are getting the first element of string

> "Fred,26.2486591339111,-80.2002334594727"

i.e.

> "F"

You need to refer to the `loc` array that you split out at the start of the loop.

Change the lines:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
    return function () {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
})(marker, i));
```

To:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, loc) {
    return function () {
        infowindow.setContent(loc[0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
})(marker, loc));
```

In order to get:

> "Fred"

Comment: Thank you for the info! When I set it to loc[0], the infowindow is now always Eric. I get a precompile message that loc is out of the scope of loc. Any suggestions?

Comment: Updated to show that `loc` should be passed in instead of `i` :)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much for the help!